# Flutter Remove scrollbar on onTap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to create a text which opens a website. Code below:

```
InkWell(
        child: Padding(
          padding: constant.paddingAllLink,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              if (icon != null) ui.getIcon(icon, constant.iconSmall, color: theme.textColor),
              if (icon != null) SizedBox(width: constant.i8),
              ui.getH9b(title),
              SizedBox(width: constant.i8),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: ()=>{ launch(url) },
      )
```

The issue is on flutter web, the text has a scroll bar which leaves a black like. How do I fix this and remove the artifact?

**with hover on text**

[image]

**without hover**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the row widget with a ScrollBar widget and set the thickness to 0